# How to access an alraedy existing sqlite3 db present in disk in the chrome?

Tags: database, google-chrome, sqlite

I have created a database `database_back.db` using `sqlite3` api and stored it in location `C:\temp\my_db.db` .

I want to access this database from the browser. when i did

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var db = openDatabase('c:\\temp\\database_hack.db','1.0','my first', 2*1024);
    var result;
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (id unique, text)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO foo (id, text) VALUES (1, "synergies")');
    });

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("SELECT Count(*) As c FROM foo", [], function(tx, r){
        console.log(tx, r);
        console.log(r.rows.item(0).c);
      },
        function(tx, r){console.log(tx, r)});
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Then i used a sqlite console to check if foo has been created in the database or not :

```
sqlite> select * from foo;
Error: No such table foo
```

I think that both these databases are different.
How can i access the sqlite database that is present at specific location ?
Can i move it to some location as specific to chrome to make it work ?

Comment: I don't think cross-site scripting protection allows you handle local files.

Comment: so i can not do this ??